# How do I effectively switch tables in Onenote 2013

Tags: microsoft-onenote-2013

Changing rows in tables of OneNote 2013 is super intuitive: Use the little sign to the left of the row and drag it to the new location. Marking more than one line works as well In the same way two tables can be merged together (just by click and drop).

For columns this is a lot clumsier. The only solution that works for me is to create a new empty column (via the menus), copy the to-be-moved column (CTRL+C), paste it (CTRL+V) in the empty column and delete the old instance (mark and delete). Cut & paste regularly leads to Onenote inserting the to-be-copied column BELOW the column to the left (at least if there is only two columns in total).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These steps aren't much better, but at least you save a formatting step and a deleting step.

1. Select the column you want to move
2. CTRL+X, or right click and click cut
3. navigate to your destination table, and click to put the cursor on the bottom cell of the column to the LEFT of where you want to insert your cut source column
4. CTRL+V, or paste it there. OneNote should handle this and place the column immediately to the right of the column whose bottom cell you selected in step 3

Note this will only work if you have the same number of rows in your source table and destination table.